# JSON to text file using Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have searched for a solution regarding this issue and I have not found one that I can understand. I am new to Python and need basic help understanding why I get the error message: TypeError:  is not JSON serializable.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/LAUCN040010000000005")

with open("C:\...MyPath...\Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dumps(r, outfile)
```

This is my simple code I am testing. I appreciate the help.

Comment: `r` is not a JSON object; you can't `dumps` something that isn't json. You can, however, first parse the bls string to a JSON object and then dumps it. I don't see much sense in that, though.

Comment: you need to also indent your json.dumps in the with block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to/from json. Just keep it as text.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/LAUCN040010000000005")

with open("C:\Users\mhoward2\Documents\Python Scripts\Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(r.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much> I now have some JSON on my hard drive. I have learned so much from stackoverflow over the years...VBA...SQL...and now Python. This is the first question I have ever had to ask.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call *.json()* and `dump` or just write the content:

```
r = requests.get("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/LAUCN040010000000005")

with open("C:\Users\mhoward2\Documents\Python Scripts\Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
     outfile.write(r.content)
```

What you are trying to write currently is:

```
 <Response [200]>
```

which is a `requests.models.Response` object.

Comment: `content` lets you access the response as bytes, so the call to `open` should probably have `wb` instead of just `w`

Comment: @iliacholy,  not in python2.

Comment: What do you mean? (not saying you're wrong, just curious)

Comment: bytes is an alias for str  in python2, `type(r.content) -> str`, in  general you should use .content with requests and let it handle the encoding.  Python 3 is obviously a different story